# Is StackExchange Just Hostile to New Users?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I am a new user, and posted my first question.  Judging by the speed from which the post was put on hold and the snide comments, the post was not given a fair chance.  Even though the comments where snide, I did not take offense and I accept that my question was too complex and needed to be dumbed downed.  So, I completely rewrote it, asking a very targeted question.  And its still on hold, which make me believe more was placed on hold quite hastily and without thought.

As a new user, what am I supposed to do to get answer I need?  Getting the right granularity can be hard, my post looks condemned and not going to get a fair change.  Keep posting different various of the question until someone for the off change someone might have time to answer it before its held?

Edit -- New Info
I took my question elsewhere, and gotten a helpful answer right off the bat.  I really think "it's not a good question" is just a convenient excuse to justify the hostility.  Still my original question is on hold, with an additional hostile comment.

Comment: Was your question on topic and as clear as possible? What exactly do you mean by "fair chance"? What were your expectations?

Comment: It was on topic, and I made it as clear as I could.  I even rewrote it.   "Fair Chance" is meant by not immediately being put on hold, and left to be closed. Especially after I rewrote it.  I expected a friendlier site.

Comment: Where is this question that you think was harshly treated?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273899/c-program-runs-odd-in-program-files-x86 seems to be your only question anywhere prior to this one.  That question seems too broad because it does not contain a C++ code snippet to isolate the portion of code you want help with, before asking for a list of anything that may need to be considered when porting it to Windows 7.

Comment: see also [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)

Comment: Actually, if you follow the proper procedure for SO questions, as a new coder, maybe 1 out of 100 questions you formulate you'll actually ask and solve the others by formulating them as questions. At least its been that way for me.

Comment: Do not interpret moderation and keeping a site clean as hostility. PLEASE

Comment: @IͶΔ Snide comments from top users are hostile.  For instance, Look at Magisch comment.  He just assumed I have never coded before.  That's just flat out hostile. (edit:  and it gets votes)  PolyGeo just flat mocks and nit picks.  I'm sorry that wasn't moderation is was just flat out  bullying?  Should I just change the word to bully now?  Is that more technically correct?

Comment: I just notice someone put where my answers is located.  The tutorial to the site said answers would be at the bottom.  There was no need for the snide comments.

Comment: @JayTee That's what flags are for. If the flagger isn't overreacting, their flag usually goes through. That said, I think you should grow a tougher skin. I don't find calling someone a new "X'er" insulting.

Comment: @JayTee I'm sorry you feel that there is hostility directed towards you but I personally can't see it in this question or the one you have posted on Stackoverflow. Perhaps the problem is that SO is not necessarily the right place for all questions and you are frustrated at that? I honestly think that, with a good question that is on-topic, you can get some amazing support from a very knowledgeable community.

Comment: @IͶΔ That's the second time you try to discredit my feedback.  My perspective is you and your friends need to grow tougher skin and take some feedback.

Comment: @JayTee I'm not discrediting anything, since I'm just another voice here, like you. My opinion doesn't weigh more than yours in any way. I'm trying to reach agreement and understanding and you're making it hard. I could've just downvoted and moved on.

Comment: I don't see the point of me even posting.  I came here, because I was the other site directed me here.  Whether or not the community agrees with me, everything gonna stay the same.

Comment: @JayTee Actually he said new coder, didn't say you never coded before. Since you said a new user, it's highly likely the two go hand in hand. It's hardly an insult to assume someone is new. Everyone was new once, it's nothing bad. That being said, he didn't even say *you* were, it was a general statement.

Comment: New user asks vague question, ignores all comments giving constructive criticism, and it's *our* fault for not accepting it.  Look, man.  You want help.  We get it.  We're also providing support **for free**.  Don't waste our time.  Show us you've tried to solve this.  Add that to your question.  Show us a modicum of respect and don't treat us as a generic debugging service.  We're *experts*.  Not a help desk.

Answer (score 8):

> As a new user, what am I suppose to do get answer I need? Getting the
>   right granularity can be hard, my post looks condemned and not going
>   to get a fair change.

The process of formulating a proper question will very often lead to the answer itself. If for instance for programming you are formulating a proper question, there are a number of steps involved that you need to take for that. (like mcve, narrowing down, debug outputs, etc). In the majority of cases as a beginner, doing that will actually solve your problem. Thats good, you've done it yourself then! But if you do all these preparations and you don't find your problem, you'll have a good question.

Just asking whatever isn't really welcome here.

Comment: Exactly what do you think I am a beginner with?  Are you assuming I am a beginner because I have a problem?

Comment: @JayTee - Maybe I'm reading emotion into your comment that isn't there - I apologize if that's the case. It seems you're upset about being referred to as a "beginner", when your own question presents yourself as "a new user". I think the message in this answer is clear and helpful to users who are beginners at asking questions on Stack Overflow, as long as you restrain yourself from inferring hostility where none may exist.

Comment: @Mogsdad The emotion is not there, I am merely following the process, which so seem to be broken because it looks like the loop stays open.  I am not inferring hostility where none may be.  I'm directly calling it out.  The word fits and is appropriate.  You seem to be hung up on it, and are completely missing my point though.

Comment: @JayTee you've gone on bashing hostility no one sees but you.

Comment: @JayTee To be honest, the only hostility I see here is from *you*, JayTee.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have answered a key part of your own question:

> As a new user, what am I suppose to do get answer I need? Getting the
>   right granularity can be hard

Asking a good question can be hard, particularly if it is at or beyond the edges of what is on-topic for a particular site.

I think the best way to ask clear and answerable questions is to learn from the advice offered when you ask any that the community tells you, through their voting, are not yet in that state.

Particularly when you are new, be ready when you post your question to make numerous edits to it, as you read and re-read it, while those early comments are being made.

The Stack Exchange Network is not hostile to new users but it cannot afford to waste more than a little of its volunteers' time on questions that are off-topic and/or unclear/unanswerable.  It is for that reason that new users may not find their hands being held for too long on arrival.  Those first few comments are there to help you and are that handholding.

Comment: You just said "The Stack Exchange Network is not hostile to new users..." then immediately followed it up with "but".  You just negated your statement.  Sure you can reword it to get around the semantics of my statement.

Comment: @JayTee Users != Questions - our focus is on question (and answer) improvement no matter whether they come from new or long term users.

Comment: I'd like to add hostility != helpfulness.  You want better questions and answers, however the process for process improvement is clearly broken.